# Draw gnu plot from file with x and y titles of graphs in Bash

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have data in a file "data" arranged in two columns i.e Bit Rate and PSNR. I want to draw gnu plot so that x-axis have title Bit rate and y-axis have title PSNR. Also show the title of graph.

```
set title "Rate Distortion Curve"
set xlabel "bit rates"
set ylabel "psnr"
set grid
gnuplot -p -e "plot 'data' with lp"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is, though you seem to be mixing `bash` commands and variables with `gnuplot` commands and variables.

Either write an entire script for `gnuplot`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot -persist
set terminal png size 1200,800
set output 'result.png'
set title "Rate Distortion Curve"
set xlabel "bit rates"
set ylabel "psnr"
set grid
plot 'data' with lp
```

Or, write a `bash` script that calls `gnuplot` as one aspect of it and which allows you the flexibility to do things with parameters and the shell before starting `gnuplot`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# file is a bash variable set to the first parameter
file=$1

# now start gnuplot and pass variables and commands to it in a "heredoc"
gnuplot <<EOF
set terminal png size 1200,800
set output "$file"
set title "Rate Distortion Curve"
set xlabel "bit rates"
set ylabel "psnr"
set grid
plot 'data' with lp
EOF
```

[image]

So, if you want to be able to run this, first you make it executable - just one time is sufficient. Let's suppose you save the above file as `plot`, you would do:

```
chmod +x plot
```

Then you can run it with

```
./plot output.png
```

and it will create an image file called `output.png`.

---

In answer to your comment, if you have two lots of data to plot on the same axes, use the following - note the comma and slash at the end of the first line:

```
plot "data.txt" using 1:2 with linespoints title 'time',  \
     "data.txt" using 1:3 with linespoints title 'size'
```

The above assumes your data looks like this, in 3 columns:

```
10 1.32632 1.8897552
11 1.33474 1.9563009
12 1.37261 2.0283514
```

Comment: I tried the second technique. I created file with name PSNR.sh and put all the code there. Now, I will call and pass data to this?

Comment: I have added some more details - please have another look.

Comment: Hi, I need to plot multiple data using multiple lines. each one will represent different parameter with same x-axis. How to do it?

Comment: @Tahir I have added some more details at the end.